# Allow only specific properties to be filled based on value of another property

Tags: typescript

### Definition

I have a generic type `GenericSettings` which has properties that are common to all types of `Setting`. So for example if it's type `info` or `toggle`, both will have the properties from this type.

What I was looking for is: Based on the type specified (`info`,
`dropdown` or `toggle`), when declaring an object of type `Setting`, that the properties follow the definitions.

### Example

For example, if it's type `dropdown`, it should make `options` a required property.

If it's type `toggle` then only `boolean` should be allowed in `value`.

And lastly, if it's just a regular type, like `info`, then only the required properties of `GenericSettings` will be needed.

### Code example

I created this [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAZRmMBLAdgcwCrXgXjgCIMAzAeyLgB9iATAJ3KjvIHd0raixzNMANjCIBuUKEiw4AcRjoYDVAGMkKDJjiEA3qDh64kmAC5EyNFlywxIfQZgAPMCYDOYRVmu26qZ1AEBDCAA5fwBbYzhXd0xPfToYZyVFKDRydAB+Fzd1awBfcRAMMAVSfyV4bD5BGFVzDQdi9DpnGTkFZVr1OB0bfUMTHiqhIgAaXX0AN38BAFcIgCNyciF-dDHevXjYJucAeXQABX8GOSc4ReWYVdB8kFAikrL4ABEmFnZ0Tqw4Brlm1vkihUZi6PVs-Xob1YHFG4z0U1mESiXVoFxWazhcGYqXQzhMAAotMVHFloiM4Ai5qSUeclujcgBKADaAF04AB6dmGLGkCnTOaRAAW5BmAjo53gSnIDBOAWK4t4BkF8Ep8DS8AEGHg-kWE3gYEFPhuBU5cAAknAANbodhK-xgJU+OBsVACARwJJXYpwfxwGboVBpCVgNgwOQ+t0SPCmNTfQiyQEdEHfWiVfhCL4aWivZjQz7JmIFUCms287lOwbp4Tk1joADkDrYqwdqAdivm2vmQgM5EiyGIqqo-havuRWFAUtxbaGxkzmm6mIhleqsI2fMRA1X4Iam-WXh8fkCIXCu+NdxAJbL0YrjFzHyoFqb6HlcFbPbgoX8lvgRGxgdxVCfk09rShAE5pK4cC3u8HBGHO2iLngAzQXmW5xAeATBGEEREGhejEmcuF7pM-I4autzgVOr7oBQJjwQua5LmQlDEZsGFHthp6MTuxDkSa7JwAAQuQBpQTApAYK2-4tIK-h6j8MrSi0riugIQA) to illustrate what I'm looking for.

Same code can be seen below.

```
type SettingType = "info" | "dropdown" | "toggle";

type GenericSetting = {
    type: SettingType;
    text: string;
    displayName: string;
    description?: string;
}

interface ToggleSetting extends GenericSetting {
    type: "toggle",
    value: boolean,
    dependsOnParent: boolean
}

interface DropdownSetting extends GenericSetting {
    type: "dropdown",
    value: string | boolean,
    options: ({text: string, value: string | boolean})[]
}

// I know that this will create a union between all
type Setting = GenericSetting | ToggleSetting | DropdownSetting;


// If type is "toggle", don't want it to be able to set "value" as a string
const toggle:Setting = {
    type: "toggle",
    value: "",
    text: "",
    displayName: "",
}

// If type is "dropdown" I wanted it to make "options" mandatory
const dropdown:Setting = {
    type: "dropdown",
    displayName: "",
    text: "",
    value: "",
}

const info: Setting = {
    type: "info",
    displayName: "",
    text: "",
}
```

Comment: Your `text` and `displayName` are required, what would you expect

Comment: Could you reduce this to a more [mre] without as many union members?  You should be able to get your point across with three or maybe even two members.  It's not clear to me what you expect to work and what to fail, or what the `toggle` and `dropdown` values are supposed to be demonstrating.  Please also consider rephrasing your text to ask an explicit and clearly-defined question.  Assuming there really is a problem here, the solution will likely be some relatively minor modification to your union, but right now I can't see through to the intent well enough in order to suggest anything.

Comment: Sorry, I'm reducing it

Comment: You're right, edited it out.

Comment: The problem is you can't have a "partially" discriminated union including `GenericSetting`; you can't say that the `GenericSetting` member should *not* apply to a `type` of `"toggle"` or `"dropdown"`; see [ms/TS#48073](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48073) which was closed as a duplicate of the request for negated types (to say `not ("toggle" | "dropdown")`).  Maybe there are workarounds but it won't be a straightforward union type.

Comment: Wait, you only want to support `"info"`/`"toggle"`/`"dropdown"`... not any possible string?

Comment: Yeah, the types of `Setting` are limited to `SettingType`

Comment: *Oh*, then you just want to make this a discriminated union as shown [in this playground likn](https://tsplay.dev/mMzJkW).  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Okay, so for every new setting type I need to create a specific interface with specified type and extend the generic properties. I think this could work but is there be another way that didn't need to have an interface for every setting type?

Comment: You only need one interface per general shape.  So if `"info"` and `"another"` are the same shape then they could have the same interface like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w6p0rm). Should I write that up or is that still not going to work for you?

Comment: Ohh, that seems more like what I was looking for! Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work you need `Setting` to be a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).  That means you need to be able to tell the difference between union members based on the discriminant property, which is `type` in your case.  But since `GenericSetting` can have any of the `SettingType`s, then checking (for example) `setting.type === "toggle"` doesn't distinguish between `ToggleSetting` (which doesn't allow a `string` `value`) and `GenericSetting` (which doesn't care).  So you pretty much don't want `GenericSetting` to be included directly in the `Setting` union, or it will "blur" all the types together.

We can replace it with a union member corresponding to the just the `SettingType`s without more specific requirements.  I'll call it `OtherSetting`, and for clarity I'll add another member to `SettingType` called `"another"` which, along with `"info"`, doesn't have anything else special about it:

```
type SettingType = "info" | "another" | "dropdown" | "toggle";

interface OtherSetting extends GenericSetting {
    type: "info" | "another"
}

type Setting = OtherSetting | ToggleSetting | DropdownSetting;
```

Now checking the `type` property will tell you which of those three members you have, two of which have specific requirements that will now be enforced:

```
const toggle: Setting = {
    type: "toggle",
    value: "", // error! string ain't a boolean
    text: "",
    displayName: "",
}

const dropdown: Setting = { // error! options is missing
    type: "dropdown",
    displayName: "",
    text: "",
    value: "",
}

const info: Setting = { // okay
    type: "info",
    displayName: "",
    text: "",
}
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhzAJYDsDmAVc0C8UBEKAZgPZ5QA++AhsscABYQBOZleAJk8WO8QO7JW+YMVSoANhDwBuALAAoBaEhQA4hGTNEAYzgIUqKLgDeCqOajKIALljwkaTJDnyLliAA9gtgM7AmBi5u7Ig+YOJUIAByVAC2NlB+AWhBFuwQPtoBYEjEyAD8vv6BCgC+CgoowMyEVNrQ6KISEHoOhp7VyOw+ahpauvYGUKauFla2eCJikngANGYWAG5U4gCuCQBGxMSSNPOj5umQXT4A8sgAClRMGt5QWzsQNGUV8lU1ddAAIlw8-MitIYdDTdXqaAIDfRoYYLczjfCcbi8ARzWFQZZrBJJIaUB67ZD7NzcXLIHy2AAUxncXiKyVQs3RK3WtJx922+KgpQAlABtAC6L0Ub2Q1SYtXqUFODGYgOhwJOYP6ssMIzc8IIyBIQjwNDojBYgteVjsUMMuCl+uVFCgjWmLUG0MoPyR-2VLle2jyfksTUktitJjR6qmzVRB0ZmImcygAHoY1BmFwmABCRLFaFUFAAcmAUCobMez3D1Rp+DDwVC4UiMXiUf25SFntJucRfwE-odZuGsfjieIKagxMQXqgoSgsVCPgMQawE1byMEhLSlYi0TiCTw5bGHTraIxzLL9Y9XtzRGIHdNRm7ccHAGtIjPIBMz1vDivq+vd8Wd4fBUA)